# How to check if two variables refer to the same DOM object?

Tags: javascript, dom

Look at the code

```
var a = $('#element');
var b = $('#element');
a == b //false
```

How to check if `a` and `b` references to same dom element ?

Regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With this comparison:

```
a[0] === b[0]
```

... as jQuery objects are sort of wrappers for DOM elements, implementing array-like access to them.

Answer (score 2):

try this comparison

```
a[0] === b[0]
```

.

```
   'foo' === 'foo' // true as both operands are Type String (i.e. string primitives)
    var a = new String('foo');
    var b = new String('foo');
    a == b // false as a and b are Type Object and reference different objects
    a === b // false as a and b are Type Object and reference different objects
    a == 'foo' // true as a and 'foo' are of different type and, the Object (a) is converted to String 'foo' before comparison
```

check  [**Javascript Comparison Operators**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
if(a.is(b)){
   // do something
}
```

`.is()` method will check if the b *is* a

Comment: never heard about is() function, is that compatible with IE6+ ?